# Time in milliseconds since epoch in the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, time

How do I get the time since the epoch, in milliseconds, in the OSX terminal?

The Linux/Ubuntu equivalent is `date +%s.%N`:

```
Linux $ date +%s.%N
1403377762.035521859
```

Which does not work in my OSX terminal:

```
OSX $ date +%s.%N
1403377800.N
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The `date` program in OS X is different than GNU's coreutils `date` program. You can install coreutils (including gnu-date), then you will have a version of `date` that supports milliseconds.

As the installation from source can be a hassle for native OS X users I advise you to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

To install these tools using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) run this oneliner in your terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Homebrew is now installed (it is wise to follow the installer's suggestions after installation). Now we will install coreutils using `brew`.

```
brew install coreutils
```

As the installation says, all commands have been installed with the prefix 'g' (e.g. gdate, gcat, gln, etc etc). If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH (`~/.bash_profile`) like:

```
PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

You can now run

```
gdate +%s.%N
```

and this will output your time since the epoch in milliseconds.

Comment: Nice. I didn't even have to add the path, `gdate` was installed in `/usr/local/bin/gdate`.

Comment: That's what you would expect. All the binaries are installed with the g prefix. In the path I provided all the same gnu-coreutils are without the g prefix. So if you add it in your path like PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" it will replace the originals. So OS X `date` becomes GNU `date` (instead of gdate)

Comment: Fine that it worked out.

Comment: Technically, the `+%s.%N` format gives the seconds down to nanosecond precision, not milliseconds.  After I used brew to install `gdate`, I checked the manpage to see whether milliseconds was available.  It's not.  It also didn't say that a precision for `%N` could be specified, but I tried it anyway.  I found that the command to get the seconds down to millisecond precision only (i.e., three decimal places) is `gdate +%s.%3N`.

Answer (score 31):

Perl is ubiquitous.

```
$ perl -MTime::HiRes=time -e 'printf "%.9f\n", time'
1557390839.244920969
```

Comment: underrated answer

Comment: ya, on mac monterey, running this gives me `16123456778.00000000000`.  It runs, but it doesn't do what the question asked on my mac.

Comment: @Ajax, I doubt it somehow is using core `time()` function, instead of `Time::HiRes::time()`, would you try to run `perl -e 'use Time::HiRes; printf "%.9f\n", Time::HiRes::time();'` ?

Comment: Your updated function does, indeed, print useful values after the `.` instead of all `0`

Answer (score 26):

In OS X, just run `date +%s` as OS X doesn't support any more precision than this in `date`'s output and any excess precision not supported by the internal representation is truncated toward minus infinity.

If you want milliseconds output, you can use the following command, although the output is just corrected by appending zeros rather than adding precision due to the aforementioned reason. The following does output correct milliseconds on systems which support the necessary precision.

```
echo $(($(date +'%s * 1000 + %-N / 1000000')))
```

<sup>Source for above command: [Unix.SE – How to get milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69322/how-to-get-milliseconds-since-unix-epoch)</sup>

If you just want a command that appends the right number of zeros in OS X, you can use:

```
date +%s000
```

Comment: OS X doesn't support `%-N`, so that doesn't do anything (and could cause trouble if the shell variable `$N` is set). Just use `date +%s000` (or `date +%s.000` if you want the decimal point).

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I mentioned this, but if OP is looking for a portable solution that does work successfully on systems which are capable of that precision, the above command works. Of course you could simply append zeros to the output but copying that to other systems which may support the extra precision would not be ideal.

Comment: Ah, I see. But since OS X's `date` command just passes `%-N` through as `N`, it can interfere with the calculation. Try setting `N=7000000000000000000`, then try the command... This is an unlikely case in practice, but I'd feel safer with something that didn't depend on the environment.

Comment: @Gordon Indeed, setting the variable would break it—I suppose the specific variable could be reset just before the command is run, but resetting variables like that is something every good script should do before running commands anyway, imo, just in case. Of course, this is all based on my assumption that the OP wants a script—edited answer to include the literal appending of zeros.

Comment: The OP asked for "time since the epoch, in milliseconds", this is an answer on how to add zero's to a string. Not the same. Although explained in the post, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @CousinCocaine This answer is for scripting. Installing your own `date` works fine on your machine, but is useless against portable scripting. For portability, this provides the closest possible value.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside for scripting and portability on OS X you are right.

Comment:  I disagree with the "for portable scripting" rationale for this answer.  This is not a complete answer on its own.  It should be an addition to the accepted answer.  Since homebrew installs the GNU date tool as `gdate`, it doesn't conflict with the existing `date` tool.  A portable script that needs millisecond times could test for the presence of `gdate` and use it. It would fall back to `date` if necessary, using the `+%s.000` format.  A *very* portable script would test the output of `date` and verify it contains the necessary information, which would allow it to run on various OSes.

Answer (score 9):

This solution works on macOS, if you consider using a bash script and have python available:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
python -c 'from time import time; print(int(round(time() * 1000)))'
```

Or write a `python` script directly:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

from time import time
print(int(round(time() * 1000)))
```

Comment: Of all the choices, the one I finally went with was modern python:
`python3 -c "from datetime import datetime; print(datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S.%f'))"`